# Multiple stores with Alt (Flux)

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

The example on the main [Alt page](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt) shows how to connect a single store to a React component using `@connectToStores`.

I wonder if we can still use `@connectToStores` to connect 2 stores to a React component. I suppose the `getStores` method will be like this:

```
static getStores() {
  return [TodoStore, TodoStore2];
}
```

but I don't know how the `getPropsFromStores` should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is answered here

https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/issues/420

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect 2 stores together for one component, wrap your component in an [AltContainer](http://alt.js.org/docs/components/altContainer/) and then reference the props the [AltContainer](http://alt.js.org/docs/components/altContainer/) passes to your component.